# CircuitBreaker Fallback method not working

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I have the below code in Billing service microservice:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/billing")
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    private BillingService service;
    
    @GetMapping("/hi")
    @CircuitBreaker(name="BillingServiceCapture", fallbackMethod = "hiFallback")
    public String hi() {
        return "Hello Khushboo!";
    }
    
    public String hiFallback() {
        return "Hello Khushboo FallBack!";
    }
```

Application.Properties file:

```
server.port=9191
spring.h2.console.enable=true
spring.application.name=billing-service
eureka.client.serviceurl.defaultzone=http://localhost:8761/eureka   
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost

management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled=true
#actuator settings
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.registerHealthIndicator=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.eventConsumerBufferSize=10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.failureRateThreshold=20
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.minimumNumberOfCalls=5
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.waitDurationInOpenState=5s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState=3 
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.slidingWindowSize=10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.BillingServiceCapture.slidingWindowType=COUNT_BASED
```

However, if I send a Get Request: localhost:8765/billing/hi
I get Hello Khushboo message.

But when I stop the BillingService microservice and again send the same request, the circuit breaker method doesn't get invoked.

Also, while accessing the Actuator Health status, I do not see circuit breaker information in the status logs which I should see.

I even added the CircuitBreaker code in OrderService which actually calls the BillingService:

```
@CircuitBreaker(name="BillingServiceCapture", fallbackMethod = "getAllBillingDetails")
    public TransactionResponse saveOrder(TransactionRequest request) {
        
        Order order=request.getOrder();
        Billing billing=request.getBilling();
        
        billing.setOrderId(order.getId());
        billing.setAmount(order.getPrice());

        Order ordermade=orderRepo.save(order);
        
        Billing billingresponse=billingproxy.getBillingDone(billing);
        
        TransactionResponse response=null;
        
        String responseStr= billingresponse.getPaymentStatus().equals("success")?"Payment processing successful":"Payment failed";
        response=new TransactionResponse(order, billingresponse.getTransactionId(),billingresponse.getAmount(),responseStr);
        
        return response;
    }
    
    public Billing getAllBillingDetails(Billing bill,Exception e) {
        return new Billing(1000,"pass",101,102,1000);
    }
```

When I call http://localhost:8765/order/bookorder - this throws a 500 internal server exception but CircuitBreaker is not called. The error is:

```
[503] during [GET] to [http://billing-service/billing/preparebill] [BillingProxy#getBillingDone(Billing)]: [Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service billing-service]
```

Please note for testing purpose I'm not starting BillingService so the instance is not available for OrderService Feign to call.

Any insights will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The `hi` method doesn't throw an Exception, so the fallback method simply isn't invoked…

Comment: Hi Slauth - I have editted the post. The code throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

The fallback method should pass the Exception parameter and return the same type as the original method:

```
public String hiFallback(Exception e) {
    return "Hello Khushboo FallBack!";
}
```

Comment: Can you ellaborate what does that mean?

Comment: as stated in the documentation "The fallback method mechanism works like a try/catch block. If a fallback method is configured, every exception is forwarded to a fallback method executor." It's important to remember that a fallback method should be placed in the same class and must have the same method signature with just ONE extra target exception parameter. https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3

Comment: I editted the post. The exception is thrown by the code. I posted that dummy method just for testing purpose.

Comment: the fallback method must have the same method signature. the fallback method of the saveOrder method does not have the same signature. the saveOrder returns TransactionResponse  object howvere the fallback method returns Billing object. Also tha passed parameters do not match

Comment: Hi Saman, thanks. I changed the return type and the parameter of the method and it worked. You can edit your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: already did thanks.  also you can use ResponseEntity<Object> in the fallback method which covers ResponseEntity<?> used in the original method.